# Web scraping articles from Google News

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-news

I am trying to web scrape googlenews with the gnews package. However, I don't know how to do web scraping for older articles like, for example, articles from 2010.

```
from gnews import GNews
from newspaper import Article
import pandas as pd
import datetime

google_news = GNews(language='es', country='Argentina', period = '7d')
argentina_news = google_news.get_news('protesta clarin')
print(len(argentina_news))
```

this code works perfectly to get recent articles but I need older articles. I saw [https://github.com/ranahaani/GNews#todo](https://pypi.org/project/gnews/) and something like the following appears:

```
google_news = GNews(language='es', country='Argentina', period='7d', start_date='01-01-2015', end_date='01-01-2016', max_results=10, exclude_websites=['yahoo.com', 'cnn.com'],
                    proxy=proxy)
```

but when I try star_date I get:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start_date'
```

can anyone help to get articles for specific dates. Thank you very mucha guys!

Comment: Can you show us your code? I believe the code snippet you shared comes directly from the documentation of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code is incorrect for `gnews==0.2.7` which is the latest you can install off PyPI via `pip` (or whatever). The documentation is for the unreleased mainline code that you can get directly off their git source.

Confirmed by inspecting the `GNews::__init__` method, and the method doesn't have keyword args for `start_date` or `end_date`:

```
In [1]: import gnews

In [2]: gnews.GNews.__init__??
Signature:
gnews.GNews.__init__(
    self,
    language='en',
    country='US',
    max_results=100,
    period=None,
    exclude_websites=None,
    proxy=None,
)
Docstring: Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
Source:
    def __init__(self, language="en", country="US", max_results=100, period=None, exclude_websites=None, proxy=None):
        self.countries = tuple(AVAILABLE_COUNTRIES),
        self.languages = tuple(AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES),
        self._max_results = max_results
        self._language = language
        self._country = country
        self._period = period
        self._exclude_websites = exclude_websites if exclude_websites and isinstance(exclude_websites, list) else []
        self._proxy = {'http': proxy, 'https': proxy} if proxy else None
File:      ~/src/news-test/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gnews/gnews.py
Type:      function
```

If you want the `start_date` and `end_date` functionality, that was only added rather recently, so you will need to install the module off their git source.

```
# use whatever you use to uninstall any pre-existing gnews module
pip uninstall gnews

# install from the project's git main branch
pip install git+https://github.com/ranahaani/GNews.git
```

Now you can use the start/end functionality:

```
import datetime

import gnews

start = datetime.date(2015, 1, 15)
end = datetime.date(2015, 1, 16)

google_news = GNews(language='es', country='Argentina', start_date=start, end_date=end)
rsp = google_news.get_news("protesta")
print(rsp)
```

I get this as a result:

```
[{'title': 'Latin Roots: The Protest Music Of South America - NPR',
  'description': 'Latin Roots: The Protest Music Of South America  NPR',
  'published date': 'Thu, 15 Jan 2015 08:00:00 GMT',
  'url': 'https://www.npr.org/sections/world-cafe/2015/01/15/377491862/latin-roots-the-protest-music-of-south-america',
  'publisher': {'href': 'https://www.npr.org', 'title': 'NPR'}}]
```

Also note:

- `period` is ignored if you set `start_date` and `end_date`
- Their documentation shows you can pass the dates as tuples like `(2015, 1, 15)`. This *doesn't seem to work* - just be safe and pass a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `feedparser` which does scrape data from embedded [Google RSS](https://rss.com/blog/how-do-rss-feeds-work/).

First, install the Python library:

```
$ pip3 install feedparser
```

Here a code snippet:

```py
import feedparser 
 
url = 'https://news.google.com/rss' 
feed = feedparser.parse(url) 
 
for entry in feed.entries: 
    print(entry)
```

The result:

```json
{
   "title":"With I-10 Closed by Fire Damage, Los Angeles Drivers Find Ways to Cope - The New York Times",
   "title_detail":{
      "type":"text/plain",
      "language":"None",
      "base":"https://news.google.com/rss?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en",
      "value":"With I-10 Closed by Fire Damage, Los Angeles Drivers Find Ways to Cope - The New York Times"
   },
   "links":[
      {
         "rel":"alternate",
         "type":"text/html",
         "href":"https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiTWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm55dGltZXMuY29tLzIwMjMvMTEvMTQvdXMvbG9zLWFuZ2VsZXMtZHJpdmVycy1mcmVld2F5LWNsb3NlZC5odG1s0gEA?oc=5"
      }
   ],
   "link":"https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiTWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm55dGltZXMuY29tLzIwMjMvMTEvMTQvdXMvbG9zLWFuZ2VsZXMtZHJpdmVycy1mcmVld2F5LWNsb3NlZC5odG1s0gEA?oc=5",
   "id":"2595334477",
   "guidislink":false,
   "published":"Wed, 15 Nov 2023 16:06:00 GMT",
   "published_parsed":time.struct_time(tm_year=2023,tm_mon=11,tm_mday=15,tm_hour=16,tm_min=6,tm_sec=0,tm_wday=2,tm_yday=319,tm_isdst=0),
   "summary":"<ol><li><a href=\"https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiTWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm55dGltZXMuY29tLzIwMjMvMTEvMTQvdXMvbG9zLWFuZ2VsZXMtZHJpdmVycy1mcmVld2F5LWNsb3NlZC5odG1s0gEA?oc=5\" target=\"_blank\">With I-10 Closed by Fire Damage, Los Angeles Drivers Find Ways to Cope</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=\"#6f6f6f\">The New York Times</font></li><li><a href=\"https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CCAiC3lQcnhaSE1lVzFZmAEB?oc=5\" target=\"_blank\">Drivers urged to avoid 10 Freeway, surface streets in downtown Los Angeles amid repair work</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=\"#6f6f6f\">KTLA 5</font></li><li><a href=\"https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMibWh0dHBzOi8va3RsYS5jb20vbmV3cy9sb2NhbC1uZXdzL2ZpcmVmaWdodGVycy1leHRpbmd1aXNoLWFub3RoZXItZmlyZS11bmRlcm5lYXRoLWFub3RoZXItbG9zLWFuZ2VsZXMtZnJlZXdheS_SAXFodHRwczovL2t0bGEuY29tL25ld3MvbG9jYWwtbmV3cy9maXJlZmlnaHRlcnMtZXh0aW5ndWlzaC1hbm90aGVyLWZpcmUtdW5kZXJuZWF0aC1hbm90aGVyLWxvcy1hbmdlbGVzLWZyZWV3YXkvYW1wLw?oc=5\" target=\"_blank\">Another fire breaks out underneath L.A. freeway</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=\"#6f6f6f\">KTLA Los Angeles</font></li><li><strong><a href=\"https://news.google.com/stories/CAAqNggKIjBDQklTSGpvSmMzUnZjbmt0TXpZd1NoRUtEd2pOMHNiVkNSR1lubFhjRUxHdVdpZ0FQAQ?hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;ceid=US:en&amp;oc=5\" target=\"_blank\">View Full Coverage on Google News</a></strong></li></ol>",
   "summary_detail":{
      "type":"text/html",
      "language":"None",
      "base":"https://news.google.com/rss?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en",
      "value":"<ol><li><a href=\"https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiTWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm55dGltZXMuY29tLzIwMjMvMTEvMTQvdXMvbG9zLWFuZ2VsZXMtZHJpdmVycy1mcmVld2F5LWNsb3NlZC5odG1s0gEA?oc=5\" target=\"_blank\">With I-10 Closed by Fire Damage, Los Angeles Drivers Find Ways to Cope</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=\"#6f6f6f\">The New York Times</font></li><li><a href=\"https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CCAiC3lQcnhaSE1lVzFZmAEB?oc=5\" target=\"_blank\">Drivers urged to avoid 10 Freeway, surface streets in downtown Los Angeles amid repair work</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=\"#6f6f6f\">KTLA 5</font></li><li><a href=\"https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMibWh0dHBzOi8va3RsYS5jb20vbmV3cy9sb2NhbC1uZXdzL2ZpcmVmaWdodGVycy1leHRpbmd1aXNoLWFub3RoZXItZmlyZS11bmRlcm5lYXRoLWFub3RoZXItbG9zLWFuZ2VsZXMtZnJlZXdheS_SAXFodHRwczovL2t0bGEuY29tL25ld3MvbG9jYWwtbmV3cy9maXJlZmlnaHRlcnMtZXh0aW5ndWlzaC1hbm90aGVyLWZpcmUtdW5kZXJuZWF0aC1hbm90aGVyLWxvcy1hbmdlbGVzLWZyZWV3YXkvYW1wLw?oc=5\" target=\"_blank\">Another fire breaks out underneath L.A. freeway</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=\"#6f6f6f\">KTLA Los Angeles</font></li><li><strong><a href=\"https://news.google.com/stories/CAAqNggKIjBDQklTSGpvSmMzUnZjbmt0TXpZd1NoRUtEd2pOMHNiVkNSR1lubFhjRUxHdVdpZ0FQAQ?hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;ceid=US:en&amp;oc=5\" target=\"_blank\">View Full Coverage on Google News</a></strong></li></ol>"
   },
   "source":{
      "href":"https://www.nytimes.com",
      "title":"The New York Times"
   }
}
```

And detailed company-based article [here](https://lobstr.io/blog/how-to-scrape-google-news-with-python).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Python requests module and xpath to get what you need without using any external packages.
Here is a snapshot of the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring



url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=google+news&&hl=es&sxsrf=ALiCzsZoYzwIP0ZR9d6LLa5U6IJ2WDo1sw%3A1660116293247&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A8%2F10%2F2010%2Ccd_max%3A8%2F10%2F2022&tbm=nws'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4758.87 Safari/537.36",
    }

r = requests.get(url,  headers=headers, timeout=30)
root = fromstring(r.text)

news = []
for i in root.xpath('//div[@class="xuvV6b BGxR7d"]'):
    item={}
    item['title'] =  i.xpath('.//div[@class="mCBkyc y355M ynAwRc MBeuO nDgy9d"]//text()')
    item['description'] =  i.xpath('.//div[@class="GI74Re nDgy9d"]//text()')
    item['published date'] =  i.xpath('.//div[@class="OSrXXb ZE0LJd"]//span/text()')
    item['url'] =  i.xpath('.//a/@href')
    item['publisher'] =  i.xpath('.//div[@class="CEMjEf NUnG9d"]//span/text()')
    news.append(item)
```

And here is what i get:

```
for i in news:
    print i

"""
{'published date': ['Hace 1 mes'], 'url': ['https://www.20minutos.es/noticia/5019464/0/google-news-regresa-a-espana-tras-ocho-anos-cerrado/'], 'publisher': ['20Minutos'], 'description': [u'"Google News ayuda a los lectores a encontrar noticias de fuentes \nfidedignas, desde los sitios web de noticias m\xe1s grandes del mundo hasta \nlas publicaciones...'], 'title': [u'Noticias de 20minutos en Google News: c\xf3mo seguir la \xfaltima ...']}
{'published date': ['14 jun 2022'], 'url': ['https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-61803565'], 'publisher': ['BBC'], 'description': [u'C\xf3mo funciona LaMDA, el sistema de inteligencia artificial que "cobr\xf3 \nconciencia y siente" seg\xfan un ingeniero de Google. Alicia Hern\xe1ndez \n@por_puesto; BBC News...'], 'title': [u'C\xf3mo funciona LaMDA, el sistema de inteligencia artificial que "cobr\xf3 \nconciencia y siente" seg\xfan un ingeniero de Google']}
{'published date': ['24 mar 2022'], 'url': ['https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/mar/24/russia-blocks-google-news-after-it-bans-ads-on-proukraine-invasion-content'], 'publisher': ['The Guardian'], 'description': [u'Russia has blocked Google News, accusing it of promoting \u201cinauthentic \ninformation\u201d about the invasion of Ukraine. The ban came just hours after \nGoogle...'], 'title': ['Russia blocks Google News after ad ban on content condoning Ukraine invasion']}
{'published date': ['2 feb 2021'], 'url': ['https://dircomfidencial.com/medios/google-news-showcase-que-es-y-como-funciona-el-agregador-por-el-que-los-medios-pueden-generar-ingresos-20210202-0401/'], 'publisher': ['Dircomfidencial'], 'description': [u'Google News Showcase: qu\xe9 es y c\xf3mo funciona el agregador por el que los \nmedios pueden generar ingresos. MEDIOS | 2 FEBRERO 2021 | ACTUALIZADO: 3 \nFEBRERO 2021 8...'], 'title': [u'Google News Showcase: qu\xe9 es y c\xf3mo funciona el ...']}
{'published date': ['4 nov 2021'], 'url': ['https://www.euronews.com/next/2021/11/04/google-news-returns-to-spain-after-the-country-adopts-new-eu-copyright-law'], 'publisher': ['Euronews'], 'description': ['News aggregator Google News will return to Spain following a change in \ncopyright law that allows online platforms to negotiate fees directly with \ncontent...'], 'title': ['Google News returns to Spain after the country adopts new EU copyright law']}
{'published date': ['27 may 2022'], 'url': ['https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/google-hit-with-fresh-uk-investigation-over-ad-tech-dominance-7938896/'], 'publisher': ['The Indian Express'], 'description': ['The Indian Express website has been rated GREEN for its credibility and \ntrustworthiness by Newsguard, a global service that rates news sources for \ntheir...'], 'title': ['Google hit with fresh UK investigation over ad tech dominance']}
{'published date': [u'Hace 1 d\xeda'], 'url': ['https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/google-down-outage-issues-user-error-8079170/'], 'publisher': ['The Indian Express'], 'description': ['The outage also impacted a range of other Google products such as Google \n... Join our Telegram channel (The Indian Express) for the latest news and \nupdates.'], 'title': ['Google, Google Maps and other services recover after global ...']}
{'published date': ['14 nov 2016'], 'url': ['https://www.reuters.com/article/us-alphabet-advertising-idUSKBN1392MM'], 'publisher': ['Reuters'], 'description': ["Google's move similarly does not address the issue of fake news or hoaxes \nappearing in Google search results. That happened in the last few days, \nwhen a search..."], 'title': ['Google, Facebook move to restrict ads on fake news sites']}
{'published date': ['27 sept 2021'], 'url': ['https://news.sky.com/story/googles-appeal-against-eu-record-3-8bn-fine-starts-today-as-us-cases-threaten-to-break-the-company-up-12413655'], 'publisher': ['Sky News'], 'description': ["Google's five-day appeal against the decision is being heard at European \n... told Sky News he expected there could be another appeal after the \nhearing in..."], 'title': [u"Google's appeal against EU record \xa33.8bn fine starts today, as US cases \nthreaten to break the company up"]}
{'published date': ['11 jun 2022'], 'url': ['https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2022/06/11/google-ai-lamda-blake-lemoine/'], 'publisher': ['The Washington Post'], 'description': [u"SAN FRANCISCO \u2014 Google engineer Blake Lemoine opened his laptop to the \ninterface for LaMDA, Google's artificially intelligent chatbot generator,..."], 'title': ["The Google engineer who thinks the company's AI has come ..."]}
"""
```